# Merge 2 svn directories into one directory automatically

Tags: shell, svn

I have 2 directories which have the similiar structure.

```
./projectA
          /directory1
                 /file1
          /directory2
                 /file2
                 /file3
                 /file4
          /directory3
          /directoryA
./projectB
          /directory1
          /directory2
                 /file3
          /directory3
          /directoryB
```

I would like to merge projectA into projectB. If a directory or file existing in A and not existing in B, do svn copy from A to B to the according target. If a file in A has an according file in B, echo a warning. How can I do this automatically? It can be shell scripts or tools....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this command you get all files that are in `projectA` but not in `projectB`, ignoring the `.svn` folder:

```
diff -qr projectA projectB --exclude=.svn | grep "^Only in projectA:" | cut -d: -f2 | sed 's/^ *//g
```

With this command you get all files that exist in both folders and that differ (i.e. files you might need to check before copying):

```
diff -qr projectA projectB --exclude=.svn | grep "^Files " | cut -d" " -f2 | sed 's!projectA!!g'
```

The second command will not work with files that have spaces in them, though.

Now that you've got two lists with the file names you need, you can easily write a small script that does the right thing with them.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Finally, we have the list of the file names. I would like to change into diff -qr ProjectA ProjectB --exclude=.svn | grep "^Only in ProjectA"|sed 's/Only in ProjectA//g'|sed 's/:\s/\//g'; so that we can get list of fullpath instead.